# Xamarin.Forms ListView Binding Issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

We are a newbie for Xamarin. We are having an issue in binding the response data from a web service to a ListView.

We debugged and we can see the the web service is successfully responding with the data but it never gets populated.

Any ideas?

It's gotta be a small thing that we are missing. We have managed to display a single entry from the data with other views (in other parts of the project) BUT not in `IEnumerable<>` or `List<>`

Here's the code:

View - RoundsPage.xaml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:AthlosifyMobile.ViewModels"
             x:Class="AthlosifyMobile.Views.RoundsPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:RoundsViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>

        <Entry Text="{Binding AccessToken}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding GetRoundsCommand}" Text="Get all rounds" />
        <Label Text="Rounds: "></Label>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rounds}" HasUnevenRows="true"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="Round 1:"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding DailyHandicap}"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding PlayedUTC}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>`
```

ViewModel - RoundsViewModel.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using AthlosifyMobile.Annotations;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using AthlosifyMobile.Services;
using AthlosifyMobile.Models;

namespace AthlosifyMobile.ViewModels
{ 
    public class RoundsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private IEnumerable<Round> _rounds;
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Round> Rounds
        {
            get
            {
                return _rounds;
            }
            set
            {
                _rounds = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand GetRoundsCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async() =>
                {
                    Rounds = await _apiServices.GetRoundsAsync(AccessToken);
                });
            }
        }

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Model - Course.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace AthlosifyMobile.Models
{
    public class Round : EntityBase
    {
        public Guid RoundID { get; set; }
        public Guid UserID  { get; set; }
        public Guid RoundCategoryID { get; set; }
        public Guid CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public int DailyHandicap { get; set; }
        public DateTime PlayedUTC { get; set; }
        public RoundCategory RoundCategory { get; set; }
        public Course Course { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RoundHole> RoundHoles { get; set; }
    }   

    public abstract class EntityBase
        {
            public DateTime CreatedUTC { get; set; }

            public DateTime LastModifiedUTC { get; set; }
        }
}
```

Services - apiservices.cs:

```
using AthlosifyMobile.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AthlosifyMobile.Services
{

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Round>> GetRoundsAsync(string accessToken)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5609/api/Rounds");
            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Round>>(json);

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first, are you certain that your GetRoundsAsync() is returning data?  2nd, your setter for Rounds is replacing the existing instance with a new instance, which may be breaking your binding.  Try explicitly setting the ListView's ItemsSource in code after you have retrieved the new data.

Comment: When we debugged this code, we can see data returning in GetRoundsAsync(). In regards #2, how do we do that?

Comment: is the data getting deserialized correctly?  For the 2nd, assign a name to your ListView in XAML, then just assign myList.ItemsSource after the data is loaded.

Comment: Data has been deseriliased correctly. Not sure how to assign this myList.ItemsSource = Rounds; ?!?! ie linking to RoundViewModel where the iEnumerable<Round> exist

Comment: in the OnAppearing event of your page, try "var data = await _apiServices.GetRoundsAsync();  myList.ItemsSource = data;"

Comment: If you looked at the code that I have, we executed via ICommand button. So we are slightly different handling on this.

Comment: I realize that.  I am suggesting you try an alternate method to see if that solves your problem.  That in turn will help you narrow down the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Understand. We just bypassed the ViewModel and straight to services. OK will try the approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to diagnose whether this is an issue with connecting the View to the ViewModel or whether your Data Service isn't working correctly. Either way, there are a few things you should do to fix this!

Firstly you are using `IEnumerable`, instead you should be using `ObservableCollection<T>`. You should always be using `ObservableCollection<T>` for Binded list views. This is explained in the xamarin docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding) (they automatically notify the view when their contents changed & update).

So you should make this change:

```
public ObservableCollection<Round> Rounds { get; }
```

Next you should verify that the bindings are correct. I would not recommend your approach of going straight to live data if you aren't familiar with xamarin. Firstly you should try adding some static objects to the view model and trying to bind them!

Disconnect your API code and call a method that creates some of your `Round` objects. Here is an example method (i use methods like these all the time when designing my ListViews UI).

```
public RoundsViewModel()
{
    Rounds = CreateSampleData();
}

private ObservableCollection<Round> CreateSampleData()
{
    ObservableCollection<Round> dummyData = new ObservableCollection<Round>();

    dummyData.Add(new Round() { Name="User", handicap=1, PlayedUTC=DateTime.Now });
    dummyData.Add(new Round() { Name="User", handicap=1, PlayedUTC=DateTime.Now });
    dummyData.Add(new Round() { Name="User", handicap=1, PlayedUTC=DateTime.Now });

    return dummyData;
}
```

At this point you will either see items in your ListView, meaning you have an issue with your API code / Implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If you don't see anything then you likely have an issue with binding and will need to verify that your view is actually connected to the View Model.

**Mvvm Helpers**

Seeing some of this code makes me feel very sorry for you, you definitely should looking into using an MVVM helper such as Prism or MVVMCross. I personally use Prism which provides a `ViewModelBase` which all ViewModels inherit from. This means all of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` code is hidden away from you (less boilerplate). It also has a dependancy service which means hooking views up to view models is as simple as registering it in the app.cs.

If you are interested in prism, watch [this video with Brian Lagunas](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Prism-for-XamarinForms-with-Brian-Lagunas) to see what Prism can do for you!

Update: There are now a few helpful libraries aside from Prism that will help with the MVVM stuff. [Refractored.MVVMHelpers](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers) and [Xamarin.CommunityToolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit) both contain an essential object: `ObservableRangeCollection`.

**ALL** code using an `ObservableCollection` should be replaced with `ObservableRangeCollection`, it is an essential object and really belongs in a microsoft maintained namespace at this point. It creates a performance benefit for updating larger collections & reduces the need for alot of boilerplate when updating the `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Hi Axemasta. It's quite interesting actually soon you put the constructor with dummy data above. The initial load was obviously dummy data and worked OK BUT surprisingly then the webservice data is OK as well. However if I took the constructor again, the list won't get displayed ?!?! Any ideas? This something to do with the initialization? Maybe?

Comment: So you would always want a constructor in your viewmodel to actually set the thing going. That is where you would either fetch data, or set off a task to fetch data.

If you breakpoint the `get` that the listview is bound too, you would see that it if getting a null. Adding the constructor and initialising the data is what you want to do!